# Are there any Egyptian hieroglyphs representing four sounds?

Tags: ancient-egypt, hieroglyphs

Based on current literature describing the Egyptian language such as Hoch (1994), Allen (2013) and Selden (2015), it adds to my understanding that egyptians developed written phonograms which could represent just one sound, a combination of two sounds such as *ms* or up to three different sounds such as *nfr*.

My question is whether there are what one may call *quadriliteral* or *tetraliteral* signs standing for four different sounds? If so, where can I find references to them?

Comment: Would this be better on the Linguistics site?

Comment: It might as well be on Linguistics.SE, but it encompasses investigation about past writeen sources and relevant bibliography, both of which are features of historical studies.

Comment: Well, I *can* move questions between sites upon request. If you change your mind, let us know. It looks like you did get an answer, so perhaps that's good enough for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are, but not many it appears. An exhaustive list can be found in *Hieroglyphenschlüssel: Entziffern, Lesen, Verstehen* by Petra Vomberg and Orell Witthuhn, but [this partial list](https://www.uni-marburg.de/cnms/aegyptologie/fachgebiet/archiv/Konsonantenliste.pdf) gives one example: F39  jmꜣḫ.